# Android DialogFragment No_Title feature affects layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have an android ***DialogFragment*** that displays a *ListView*, each row containing a title and image.  Everything displays fine until I remove the title from the DialogFragment with **getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);**

Once I remove the title, the images stop displaying in the ListView and all that displays are the titles.  How could FEATURE_NO_TITLE possibly affect the display of the ListView within the DialogFragment?  Literally no other lines of code change - just that one, and the images stop displaying in the ListView.

*Dialog Fragment OnCreate*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_photo_dialog_fragment, container);

    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Button closeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.photosListView);
    listadapter = new PhotoListAdapter(getActivity());
    listview.setAdapter(listadapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

*XML for the fragment contains nothing more than a ListView and Button inside a LinearLayout...*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/photosListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

*ListAdapter relevant classes*

```
int[] mResources = {R.drawable.basketball, R.drawable.bodyweight, R.drawable.boulder, R.drawable.boxing, R.drawable.cardio,
        R.drawable.crossfit, R.drawable.olympic, R.drawable.racquet, R.drawable.run, R.drawable.spin, R.drawable.squash,
        R.drawable.swim, R.drawable.volleyball, R.drawable.weight, R.drawable.yoga};
String[] pictureNames = {"basketball", "bodyweight", "boulder", "boxing", "cardio", "crossfit", "olympic", "racquet", "run",
        "spin", "squash", "swim", "volleyball", "weight", "yoga"};

public PhotoListAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pictureNames[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_list_row_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.activityNameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityName);
        holder.activityImageIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityImage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    task = new CreateClassSetImageTask(position, holder.activityNameTV, holder.activityImageIV);
    task.execute();

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView activityNameTV;
    ImageView activityImageIV;
}
```

*XML for ListView row*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView android:id="@+id/activityName"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/activityImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Async Task to Load Images

```
public class CreateClassSetImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    WeakReference<TextView> textViewReference;
    int pictureNum;

    public CreateClassSetImageTask(int pictureNumIn, TextView activityNameTVIn, ImageView activityIVIn) {

        pictureNum = pictureNumIn;
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(activityIVIn);
        textViewReference = new WeakReference<TextView>(activityNameTVIn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap resultBitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && resultBitmap != null && textViewReference != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
            }
            final TextView textView = textViewReference.get();
            if (textView != null){
                textView.setText(pictureNames[pictureNum]);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mContext.getResources(), mResources[pictureNum], 100, 100);
    }


}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: Commonly I put requestFeature directive in onResume. In onCreateView it doesn't seem to work (even if I never experienced your issue). What does it happens if you try doing this?

Comment: @thetonrifles thanks for the idea - I tried it but it throws a runtime exception "requestFeature() must be called before adding content" - since onCreateView (or even if I switched to using onCreate) always gets called before onResume, I'm not sure how I would fix that - content will have to be added before getting to onResume, which means I can't call requestFeature() in onResume.  How do you get requestFeature() to work in onResume?  Either way though, I'm not sure that's the problem here - when I call it, it works - the title goes away.  It just destroys the rest of the fragment as well...

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I made confusion with background and width/height definition. Try adding requestFeature in onCreateDialog method.

Comment: @thetonrifles no luck with that either

Comment: Uhm ok... I'm trying to implement your same dialog for checking behavior. I have a couple of questions. In adapter I see you use mResources in getCount and pictureNames in getItem. Which is the difference between these arrays? I see also that you are using an AsyncTask for loading pictures to be displayed. Is it possible for you to share its implementation?

Comment: thanks!  mResources is an array of the resource IDs to access the pictures while pictureNames is just a string name for the picture which I save - in the future, I look at the string name and know which type of image they selected. I'll add the Async task implementation to the original questions.

Comment: mResources and pictureNames are added as well, to the top of the ListAdapter.  The part that I really don't understand is how could removing the dialog title affected anything that happens with the rest of the code - it should be totally unrelated...

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue but while working on it I've experienced some UI troubles and realised a couple of things. 1. Titles and resources are static so you don't need an AsyncTask for displaying them (this is just an improvement). 2. Instead of overriding onCreateView you should override onCreateDialog and just avoid setting title in AlertDialog.Builder. In this way I had dialog properly displayed without title.

Comment: I've posted an answer with full code of dialog. Hope this will work fine for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...instead of using `getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Set `DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE` in the onCreate method of the Dialog like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
    style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
    theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
    setStyle(style, theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the whole code for your dialog. Basically I removed the AsyncTask (you can eventually restore it if you need for example to download pictures from network) and override method `onCreateDialog` instead of `onCreateView`.

```
public class PhotoDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static PhotoDialog newInstance() {
        return new PhotoDialog();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pick_photo_dialog_fragment, null);
        Button closeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.photosListView);
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new PhotoListAdapter(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                //do stuff
            }
        });
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // REMOVE setTitle in case you don't want dialog title to be shown
        //builder.setTitle("Dialog Title");
        builder.setView(v);
        return builder.create();
    }

    private static class PhotoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static ListItem[] _ITEMS = {
                new ListItem("basketball", R.drawable.basketball),
                new ListItem("bodyweight", R.drawable.bodyweight),
                new ListItem("boulder", R.drawable.boulder),
                new ListItem("boxing", R.drawable.boxing),
                new ListItem("cardio", R.drawable.cardio),
                new ListItem("crossfit", R.drawable.crossfit),
                new ListItem("olympic", R.drawable.olympic),
                new ListItem("racquet", R.drawable.racquet),
                new ListItem("run", R.drawable.run),
                new ListItem("spin", R.drawable.spin),
                new ListItem("squash", R.drawable.squash),
                new ListItem("swim", R.drawable.swim),
                new ListItem("volleyball", R.drawable.volleyball),
                new ListItem("weight", R.drawable.weight),
                new ListItem("yoga", R.drawable.yoga)
        };

        static class ViewHolder {

            TextView activityNameTV;
            ImageView activityImageIV;

        }

        static class ListItem {

            String title;
            int icon;

            public ListItem(String title, int icon) {
                this.title = title;
                this.icon = icon;
            }

        }

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public PhotoListAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return _ITEMS.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return _ITEMS[position];
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_list_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.activityNameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityName);
                holder.activityImageIV = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityImage);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            ListItem item = (ListItem) getItem(position);

            holder.activityNameTV.setText(item.title);
            holder.activityImageIV.setImageResource(item.icon);

            return convertView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't work for me, I have the same issue as before, when the title is removed, the formatting goes to junk.  The answer from @wasterley fixed it though.